# any vector as a linear combination of other vectors plus a perpendicular vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that given a vector $v \in R^m$ we can write $v=Bw+z,$ where $B$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, $w \in R^n$, and $z\in R^m$ and orthogonal to the space spanned by the columns of $B$.

I was reading a proof and the above was used with no explanation. So I am assuming it is true but I do not see it.

Comment: The scalar product is non degenerate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and something even more general is true: for any subspace $\mathcal{V} \subset \mathbb{R}^m$,  any vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ can be represented as $\vec{u} + \vec{z}$, where $\vec{u} \in \mathcal{V}$ and $\vec{z} \in \mathcal{V}^\perp$.

In fact, $\vec{u}$ will be the orthogonal projection of $\vec{v}$ onto $\mathcal{V}$, and $\vec{z} = \vec{v} - \vec{u}$ will be the component of $\vec{v}$ orthogonal to $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: So in my case: $V$ would be the column space of $B$ which is a subset of $R^m.$ And so any $v \in R^m$ can be represented as $u+w$, where $u\in V$ and $w\in V^{\perp}$?

Comment: Exactly! And any vector in $\mathcal{V}$ (the column space of $B$), must be expressible as $B \vec{a}$, for some $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. (Here the $\vec{w}$ in the question is my $\vec{a}$).

Comment: To clarify, I just realized, your $w$ (the one in the answer) is not the same as the $w$ in the question right?

Comment: So $Bw$ in the question would be the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the column space of $B$ and $z$ would be the component of $v$ orthogonal to the space spanned by the columns of $B$?

Comment: Yes, the $\mathcal{w}$ in my answer is different. I've changed my answer, now you can just take $\vec{z} = B \vec{w}$ directly. But yes, $B\vec{w}$ is the orthogonal projection, and when you subtract this from $\vec{v}$, what's left is a component that is orthogonal to the column space of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

If $W$ is a subspace of the inner product space $V$, then $V=W\oplus W^\perp$. That is, any $v\in V$ can be written as a sum of a vector in $W$ and one on $W^\perp$. Now, if $W$ is the column space of the matrix $B$, then by definition any $w\in W$ can be written as a linear combination $\sum_i a_iB_i$ of the columns $B_i$ of $B$. Note that we don’t require that they be linearly independent. If they’re not, that just means that this linear combination isn’t unique. That sum, however, can be written as the matrix product $$B\begin{bmatrix}a_i\\\vdots\\a_n\end{bmatrix}.$$